# Add current time to Visual Studio 2015 status bar

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Does anyone know how to add the current time to either the status bar in VS2015 or the menu bar?

I always have my Windows task bar set to auto hide and would like to see the current time while coding. (I don't wear a watch as a rule)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to build a [VSSDK package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441.aspx) and invoke [IVsStatusBar.SetText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsstatusbar.settext.aspx) periodically. Additionally, I'd consider implementing and registering an [IOleComponent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop.iolecomponent.fdoidle.aspx) interface, so that the FDoIdle method is invoked periodically, and call IVsStatusBar.SetText from there.

Searching on http://github, on IVsStatusBar should pull up a few examples that do this.